# iOS Background Access Token Refresh

Tags: ios, access-token, background-process, refresh-token

I am looking to extend the expiry time of an access token by refreshing the token in the background. The expiry time is currently set to 30 minutes (server side) and this value is not to be changed, the idea is that every 29 minutes I will call a method that refreshes the access token to keep it alive for a further 1 and a half hours (meaning the access token stays alive for almost 2 hours). I have read that background tasks should take up to 5 second to complete then if more time is required to use UIKit, although this will only allow a further few minutes to complete the tasks needed.

Are there any special circumstances that will allow me to do this in background, or is there a better way to do this? Thank you for any help!

Comment: you should use oath or similar solution and update tokens only when you need it

Answer (score -1):

In AppDelegate.swift do this.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: (60.0 * 29.0), target: self, selector: #selector(self.doThisEvery29Min), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    return true
}

@objc func doThisEvery29Min () {
    if Constant.uToken != nil {
        ServiceManager.sharedInstance.RefreshTokens() {
            (result) in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let responce):
                // update token
            case .FailureDueToService(let error):
                print(error)
                break
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Timer` won't fire when the app is suspended.

Comment: @Paulw11 As per my understanding he means background not suspended state .. he won’t be able to execute any code if the app was suspended.

Comment: The suspended state is the state where an app is not actively executing in the background. When an app moves from the foreground it runs briefly in the background until it moves to the suspended state. It remains suspended unless the user brings it back to the foreground or something causes it to move temporarily to background execution (location update, silent push). A timer won’t cause the app to move from the suspended state.

Comment: @Paulw11 then what would you suggest be the solution?

Comment: They need to use an authentication system with a longer refresh token period or accept the fact that the user may need to re-authenticate if their token expires.  Depending on how they obtain the token initially, they may be able to hold the user's credentials in the keychain and simply re-authenticate automatically when required.

Comment: Thank you for your reply's! After a long discussion we decided to scrap this as this will just prolong the user experience issue we are having. Instead of looking to extend the token life to 2 hours we are working on making the login process easier for the user e.g. Face ID, Touch ID, pin code